# How to fetch a range of numbers using like operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I'm trying to fetch the records which are matching my condition.

I'm using wildcard operator but it's not fetching the records as I expect.

I have multiple records in my table and I'm using the query below:

```
select *
from My_table
where RegNum like '117[15-24]%'
```

I thought above query will fetch the records from 11715 to 11724, but currently it's fetching records from 11710 to 11719. I got to know that `%` wildcard operator will consider single digits only.

Is there any other way to use two digit number in wildcard operator or is there any other solution to fetch the records what I'm looking for?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.  Your `like` expression uses non-standard functionality.

Comment: I used the below query to fetch expected output
select * from My_Table where RegNum like '117[15-24]%'
The output from the above  query was
11710
11711
11712
11713
11714
11715
11716
11717
11718
11719

Answer (score 1):

I speculate that you are using SQL Server.  When comparing numerical ranges, the best thing to do is to just use an inequality.  If your `RegNum` column is text, then cast it to integer first and then compare:

```
SELECT *
FROM My_table
WHERE (CAST RegNum AS int) BETWEEN 11715 AND 11724;
```

If you want to use `LIKE`, we might be able to try:

```
SELECT *
FROM My_table
WHERE RegNum LIKE '1171[5-9]' OR RegNum LIKE '1172[0-4]';
```

Comment: Is it possible to use two digit in bracket and get desired output?

Comment: No, because regex syntax does not work that way.  Regex knows nothing of our numbers, it only knows single/multiple characters.  I recommend doing an inequality comparison in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you want is perhaps better captured by:

```
where left(regnum, 5) between '11715' and '11724'
```

Not all databases support `left()`, in those, use the substring function instead.

You have a logic fallacy in wanting to use `like` for numeric ranges.  `like` is for strings.  If you want numeric ranges, use numbers.  You could do this with the above condition:

```
where cast(left(regnum, 5) as int) between 11715 and 11724
```

But this is logically equivalent to the original string comparison.